# swift5 UILabel Clickable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I am learning iOS development. And I want to make UILabel clickable
Here is what I have done but with no result.

```
@IBOutlet weak var coordinate: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        coordinate.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        
        let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(uiLabelClicked()))
        coordinate.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        coordinate.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Below is a function that is expected to perform an action when label is clicked.

```
 @objc func uiLabelClicked(){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Coordinate", message: "I have been clicked...", preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            debugPrint("clicked")
            
        }
```

I apologize for my English I am using google translator.

Comment: Don't you have a crash? `func uiLabelClicked()` doesn't match `#selector(uiLabelClicked(_sender: ))`.

Comment: @Larme that is mistake I did make when post to this forum but. I have tried to name the function fun uiLabelClicked() and #selector(uiLabelClicked() and I got nothing.then I tried func uiLableCliced(_sender:Any) and there was no action performed when I clicked the label

Comment: try using an `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of an `UIGestureRecognizer`

Comment: @birkoof still am not getting any action performed

Comment: try to remove the parentheses in your selector `#selector(uiLabelClicked())`, like this: `#selector(uiLabelClicked)`.. with parentheses present should normally give a compile error

Comment: @birkoof I am calling the function without invoke, I know the error I would get is `#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var coordinate: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    coordinate.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelAction(_:)))
    coordinate.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    coordinate.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func labelAction(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Coordinate", message: "I have been clicked...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    debugPrint("clicked")
}
```